# php laravel WHERE Mysql, I cannot select more than one product, Documentation FAIL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm writing due to problem which I have encountered today.
I am writing small project SHOPPING CART with books in Laravel/PHP using MySQL provided by phpMyAdmin. I wanted to create SEARCH, to find book. All books appear on one page so without SEARCH it's difficult to find book which I want.

I started building SEARCH for it. Everything is almost fine. 
1. I created FORM on my `index.blade.php`
2. It sends to `routes.php`
3. Then to Controller, where I use function:

```
public function getSelectedBooks(Request $request)
{
    $variable = 'searched pattern';
    $variable = $request->input('search_id');
    $products = Product::all()->where('title',$variable);
    return view('shop.ViewSelectedBooks', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

This function works but weird. All problem is  **where('title',$variable);**
I cannot put **where('title','LIKE','%$variable%');** or whatever. Even I cannot select books.id > 10. Function works only for one book, it seems to be like
where('title',$variable); =====> where title = variable, and I cannot modify it
What is stranger, in Laravel documentation I found other commands with WHERE, which are inappropriate to my Laravel. example:
DB::table('products')->where('id', '=', 10)->get(); It makes errors.

Please help me

Comment: Possibly try concatenating the % to variable like this and running it. `$products = Product::all()->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $variable . '%');`

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesnt work. It doesn't find any records.
Function WHERE takes arguments: key:string, value, [strict:bool = true]. Third argument is probably optional because with 2 arguments it works. It's strange.

Comment: One last option i can offer is trying `Product::where('title', $variable)
    ->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . $variable . '%')->get();`

Comment: THANKS a lot ! It works finally. You saved my life !